# is there a faster way to get a YouTube clip's title than this?

Tags: php, xml, api, youtube

Currently i'm using the following, which seems quite slow for multiple clips:

```
static function get_yt_title($clip_id){    
    $feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $clip_id;
    $entry = @simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
    if($entry){
        $video= new stdClass;
        $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
        $video->title = ucwords(strtolower($media->group->title));
        return $video->title;   
    }
    else{
        return FALSE;
    }
```

any more efficient methods than this for doing 5-10 clips at a time with php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

- Get a faster server.
- Minute, but clean your code

  ```
  static function get_yt_title($clip_id)
  {
      $entry = @simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $clip_id);
      return ($entry) ? ucwords(strtolower($entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/')->group->title)) : false;
  }
  ```

Use JSON Feeds: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/?alt=json by appending the `?alt=json` to the URI

Comment: Most likely, that's just not true. There is not much computational power needed for what he tries to do. The most time consumed is in network i/o. Things that might help are: move your server closer to the gdata server or maybe there's a request format that is easier to parse. Besides that, there is nothing much you can do.

Comment: When I said faster server, I was talking relative to connection speeds, and was being slightly sarcastic when it comes down to the code, just cleaned out the variables that was not really required.

Comment: Also might help if they have a less verbose format available like json? (less data to send over the wire?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is.
As far as i can tell this is the recommended way to get meta data like that.

There's one other thing I can think of and that is scraping the html off of youtube.com, i can almost guarantee you it isn't faster and sure as hell isn't reliable.

Comment: haha, yeah scraping is seriously slow and like you mentioned a pain to sustain!

Comment: would using curl to retrieve the xml help with the speed? then just parse the xml as a string?

Answer (score 0):

If you do this a lot for the same clip id's you could cache the results on your server.